# how to search the second value in the same row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've a table row where the values looks like below.

**Table Name:** Movies
   **Row name:** Genere

**Row 1** Action,Crime,Thriller
   **Row 2** Adventure
   **Row 3** Mystery,Thriller

```
SELECT * FROM  `Movies` WHERE  `Genere` IN ('thriller',  'animation');
```

But the values are not fetching eventhough the word thriller exists.

**1)** Is the way I saved in MySQL table in phpMyAdmin correct?
   **2)** How to access second or third values using `IN`?

Comment: Change the DB structure and normalize it.

Comment: See also [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `Movies` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 'thriller', `Genere`) 
                           OR FIND_IN_SET( 'animation', `Genere`)
```

Comment: i believed his mention was without or, it is possible?

Comment: @user3600910:- Then I am afraid, it is not possible. And OP has to change the DB structure!